# How can i get class variable in run method thread (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

My problem concern thread. i want to get var(class variable) from method run but can't get and
i don't know what happed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Interpreter_controller extends Thread{
    ArrayList<String> var;


    public Interpreter_controller(ArrayList<String> var) {
        this.var = var;
        System.out.println(this.var.isEmpty());
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.var.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

when i start thread from

```
Interpreter_controller control = new Interpreter_controller(array_list_variable);
control.start();
```

Output is

false

true

What should I do to get var from run method?

New Edit

I delete extends Thread then result is correct but i want to use thread in this class

My goal is pass arraylist from another class to use in thread class(run method)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do at all. First you are assigning your ArrayList<String> called `var` to something during static init (whatever SymbolTable.get_all_input() is), then you reassign it during the constructor to whatever you are passing in. Then you are trying to print isEmpty from a member called abc which I do not see anywhere. What do you mean by "get var from run"? What are you actually trying to do? You can't return a value from run. If you want to access `var` from run, you can just do that. It is a field in your object.

Comment: sorry i edited code again

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to replicate your problem. Running your program above gives the output `false false` when `array_list_variable` is not empty, `true true` otherwise. Are you sure your problem isn't related to concurrency?

Comment: Well from the new code you've provided, you should get the same isEmpty result from both queries. If you pass array_list_variable in to the constructor but then go on to add to it before `control.start();` then indeed you may find it's not empty anymore. I doubt this is a thread problem because the construction is on the same thread. If isEmpty returns false in the constructor then it is not empty. It seems like either you have gone on to change the list (but haven't shown how) or are getting unexpected results because the result you are expecting is incorrect.

Comment: To add on to what @Daemon said, if this is indeed a concurrency problem it's because of code you haven't shown us. For example, as I hinted, if you go on to change the list _during_ execution of `run()`, the run thread may not see the changes immediately. Otherwise you should get the same return value from both queries. From the looks of it, your `run()` is not a long enough task to encounter visibility problems.

Comment: I delete extends Thread then result is correct but i want to use thread in this class

Comment: My goal is to pass Arraylist<String> from another class to use in thread class(run method)

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is pass arraylist from another class to use in thread
>   class(run method)

Take a look at this:

```
class Tmp implements Runnable {

  public Object runArg;

  public Tmp(Object arg) {
      runArg = arg;
  }

  public void run() {
      // thread job
  }
}
```

Use:

```
new Thread(new Tmp("Hello World")).start();
```

So you have to create a new class rather than using anonymous class.

**NOTE**: Unless you are using J2ME, you should NOT use native `Thread`. Many problems would occur with you. You should use [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) by using [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) classes:

```
private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCashedThreadPool();

...

pool.submit(new Tmp("HelloWorld"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Following will give you head start. Make sure list is synchronized.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.execute();
    }

    public void execute() throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
        List<Thread> tlist = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread t = new SomeThread(list, i);
            t.start();
            tlist.add(t);
        }

        while (true) {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < tlist.size(); i++) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if (!tlist.get(i).isAlive()) {
                    j++;
                    for (String s : list) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (j == tlist.size()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeThread extends Thread {

        private List<String> list;
        private int number;
        private long sleepTime;

        public SomeThread(List list, int number) {
            this.list = list;
            this.number = number;
            sleepTime = new Random(number).nextInt(500);

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                list.add(number + " wake up from sleep");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wow I solve my problem already from your code. Thank you very mush user2880879;

Comment: I edit my code from ArrayList<String> var; to List<String> var= new ArrayList<String>()